# ReactJS manipulating objects data extracted from SQLITE3 Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, reactjs, sqlite

I am working on a full stack application. I want to query my database for information and for it to show in a different input box. I successfully query my database and retrieve the information, but I can't put the actual information into the input area.

From the console.log I found out it is an object, and I looked for tutorials, but they still don't help me. I can convert it to a string and put it there, but it won't help me, as I need the specific column - for example, { "title": "Back to the Future" } - this is similar to mine, and I only want to extract "Back to the Future".

I tried with "Object.title", JSON.parse and then trying to access its properties, but still nothing. I get undefined at best. Here is the code in question.

MainFile.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Control1.css';
import axios from "axios";

class editShowing extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
           showingId: '',
           title: '',
           showingsList: [],
       }
       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
       this.onChangeShowingID = this.onChangeShowingID.bind(this);

   }

   onChangeShowingID(event){
       this.setState({showingId: event.target.value});
   }

   onChangeTitle(event){
       this.setState({title: event.target.value});
   }


   handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

       axios.get('/api/getShowings',

       {
           params: {
               showingId: this.state.showingId
           }
               })
               .then(response => {
                   const { showingsList } = response.data
                this.setState({ showingsList });
               console.log(showingsList.title)
       })
    }


   render(){
       const { showingsList } = this.state
        return(
            <div>


                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1> A new title to test GitFlow </h1>

                <input onChange = {this.onChangeShowingID} type = "text" name = "showingId" placeholder = 'hi' value = {this.showingId}></input>
                <input onChange = {this.onChangeTitle} value = {showingsList} type = "text" name = "title" placeholder = "title" />
                <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
                </form>


            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default editShowing;
```

Server.js bit

```
app.get('/api/getShowings', (req,res) => {
  console.log("I communicate with server.js")
  datalayer.getShowings(req.query.showingId,
    (err, result) => {
      res.send(result);
    })
});
```

DataLayer.js bit

```
    module.exports.getShowings = (showingId, callback) => {
    console.log("I connect to datalayer")
    let sql = `SELECT title FROM showings WHERE id = ?;`
    console.log("SQL CONNECTS")
    db.get(sql, [showingId], (err, res) => {

        if (err){
            throw err;
        }


        console.log(res)
        return callback(null, res)
    })
}
```

To summarise, I want to put the data (only the actual title, not the whole object) of "ShowingsList" into the "title input", and I have a lot of options, but to no avail. I have been learning React.JS for the past 2 weeks.

Comment: Can you do console.log(response.data) in axios and share. So that we know how the data looks like and we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am extra lucky and found a solution 5 minutes after posting it. In the datalayer, instead of res you need to put `row.title` or the actual information you need from the database. My other mistake was that in the main jsx file I initiated ShowingsList as an object, so I changed it to a normal string, and it now works.